# can Flex return a string match to bison

Tags: string, bison, flex-lexer

I'm writing a Bison/Flex program to convert LaTeX into MathML.  At the moment, dealing with functions (i.e. \sqrt, \frac, etc) works like this, with a token for every function

```
\\frac         {return FUNC_FRAC;}
```

and passes the token FUNC_FRAC back to bison, which plays its part in the description of this subtree:

```
function: FUNC_FRAC LBRACE atom RBRACE LBRACE atom RBRACE {$$ = "<mfrac>" + $3 + $6 + "</mfrac>";}
```

But this means that I need to define and juggle a potentially unlimited number of tokens.  What I would like to do is something like this, which doesn't work as written.  In flex:

```
\\[A-Za-z]+[0-9]*  {return the-matched-string;}
```

and in bison:

```
function: "\frac" LBRACE atom RBRACE LBRACE atom RBRACE {$$ = "<mfrac>" + $3 + $6 + "</mfrac>";}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Flex should return the abstract token value to Bison.

You can find the lexeme (the string matched) in Flex in the value:

```
yytext
```

And so you can do:

```
{id}    { yylval->strval=strdup(yytext); return(TOK_ID); }
```

And so forth. The `yylval` struct relates IIRC to the bison union/whatever you are using to evaluate past the token-type .. so I might have in Bison

```
%union {
    char *strval;
    int intval;
    node node_val;
}
```

Returning anything other than a token-type will break the automaton in Bison. Your Bison actions can access such as:

```
id_production: TOK_ID
    { 
        $<node_val>$ = create_id_node(yylval.strval);
        xfree(yylval.strval); // func makes a copy, so we are cool.
    }
```

And so on. Any more explanation than this and I will probably start repeating documentation. Things to consult:

1. Dragon Book (as always)
2. Modern Compiler Implementation in C (great for getting started)
3. [Bison docs](http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/)
4. [Flex docs](http://www.gnu.org/software/flex/)

**Good Luck**

Comment: I wish I didn't see the question ... makes me want to finish old projects ;)

Comment: the Lex and Yacc book also has a simple calculator example that adds support for functions, and shows how to avoid hand code each function and build a table in the yacc/bison, using the above TOK_ID style, with the heavy lifting done in create_id_node